# How to let user to type in the type box and then push that value to the list?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Currently, I am using this code:

```js
var todoList = [
  "Take a shower"
];

function addItem() {
  var inputs = document.getElementById('new-item');
  var newItem = inputs.value;
  todoList.push(newItem);
  render();
  inputs.value = "";
}

function render() {
  var htmlList = document.getElementById('todo-List');
  var content = todoList.map(function(item) {
    return "<li>" + item + "</li>"

  });

  htmlList.innerHTML = content.join('');
}

render()
```

```html
<section id="story">
  <input id="new-item" type="text" />
  <button onclick="addItem()">Add</button>
  <ul id="todo-list"></ul>
```

I want to let users type in the type box`(<input id="new-item" type="text"/>)` and when they click the Add button`(<button onclick="addItem()">Add</button>)` the value in the type box will be pushed to the `<ul>` list.The problem is my code above does not work, can you tell me what is wrong with my code and how to fix that problem? Thank you.

Comment: In your JS you have `todo-List` instead of `todo-list`. Just a typo.

Comment: As @aca correctly observes, it's just a typo; see the demo: https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/b3y71vok/1/

Answer (score 1):

your code is fine, you just wrote wrong document.getElementById('todo-list'); be document.getElementById('todo-List');

Answer (score 0):

You had a typo in your code, as you wrote `todo-List` instead of `todo-list`.

```js
var todoList = [
  "Take a shower"
];

function addItem() {
  var inputs = document.getElementById('new-item');
  var newItem = inputs.value;
  todoList.push(newItem);
  render();
  inputs.value = "";
}

function render() {
    // corrected the "todo-List" typo below:
  var htmlList = document.getElementById('todo-list');
  var content = todoList.map(function(item) {
    return "<li>" + item + "</li>"

  });

  htmlList.innerHTML = content.join('');
}

render()
```

```html
<section id="story">
  <input id="new-item" type="text" />
  <button onclick="addItem()">Add</button>
  <ul id="todo-list"></ul>
</section>
```